# how to remove python package installed by distutils

Tags: 20.04, package-management, python, tensorflow

When trying to install the TensorFlow Python package on Ubuntu 20.04, the install script failed because it couldn't remove the existing Python package 'wrapt'. Error msg said the reason was it was installed by distutils, and couldn't determine its components to remove.

I tried `sudo pip3 uninstall wrapt`, and got the same error message.

How can I remove the wrapt package?

Comment: Does it show up when you run `pip3 list`?

Comment: yes, but as stated in my post pip3 can't remove it. Error message is same as that given by TensorFlow installer.

Comment: Can you edit to post the exact error message? Please don't put a screenshot. Rather, post the output as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to avoid the problem by installing TensorFlow in a virtualenv, as recommended by the TensorFlow install guide page.

Otherwise, it appears I would have to dive into the distutils documentation on python.org to figure out how to remove a distutils installed package.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: @denNorske Considering it's a self-answer (OP and answer author are the same), it's tough to say that it wasn't a valid workaround for the OP's *root problem* at least.  :-)

Comment: Please self-accept your answer so that the question gets closed out, otherwise the question will get bumped (sometimes years) later with no accepted-answer.  You can always change the accepted answer later if someone posts a better solution for you.